# How can I figure out how to remove this pipe?

Tags: basement, pipe, well, basement-refinishing

I'm beginning work on finishing my basement and am removing things from the walls before insulating and framing. In one corner, about a foot and a half off the ground, there's a copper(?) pipe that curves 90 degrees and then ends in a cap. It has at least one purpose, because the main breaker box ground is connected to it. I plan on having an electrician move that ground during other repairs, at which point I'd like to remove the pipe.

Is there a way I can tell if there's anything connected to it that would cause problems if I just cut the pipe? Or should I be going right to calling a plumber to have them handle the mystery pipe?

EDIT:

We're pretty sure we've figured out *what* it is - a neighbor reminded us that the subdivision used to have a communal well, but it was replaced with individual wells at some point. At this point, I'm pretty confident that this was the original inlet from the communal well. The new question is, how much water would come out if I cut it?

[image]

Comment: in my previous home, there was something like this that was a newer copper water service pipe fed through the older service pipe. had a similar curve but upwards. Some call this a trenchless replacement I think. Where is the water service and meter located in relation to this?

Comment: We're on a well, and the well supply line is in the opposite corner. I don't _think_ this property has ever been on city water, but this is the closest point to the street if it was coming from that direction.

Comment: That lead from the conduit to this pipe had better not be the primary grounding from the panel! That's supposed to be a continuous piece of wire! At least it is on current code. Maybe when the house was built this was still acceptable...

Comment: No chance of gas? Copper would be unusual for gas anyway, except old propane, and propane and basements are a bad combination so most likely not...but you do say it's away from the well side and close to the street...

Comment: @FreeMan - there are two connections there. There's a tab coming off the conduit itself, and also a wire _in_ the conduit.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can tell if there's anything connected to it that would cause problems if I just cut the pipe?

Make sure you are equipped with the tools and materials needed to repair the pipe (e.g., flux, solder, torch, emery cloth/wire brush, pipe cap, etc.) if necessary, then shut off the well pump and drain the water system (hot and cold) at the lowest point(s) available. Be prepared to catch additional water when you cut off that cap with a tubing cutter or hacksaw. Stand by while someone turns the water back on briefly.

If it is in service, you could still cut it back to a more convenient length prior to re-capping it.

Comment: _Exploritory surgery_ probably isn't your best move.